# Garbage-Free Client Coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get the coordinates of the mouse in my winform.

```
  myMousePosition = myForm.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)
```

This works, but it generates garbage (Heap allocation). Since I call this method often that's a problem.

```
  myMousePosition.X = Control.MousePosition.X - myForm.Location.X;
  myMousePosition.Y = Control.MousePosition.Y - myForm.Location.Y;
```

This doesn't work, since there is also the title bar to take into account.
Any suggestions?

EDIT: a bit more info. VS2010 profiling wizard says there are thousands of instances of type drawing.point generated when I use the PointToClient method. The thing is, I am not creating a new variable in my Update method, so where are these instances coming from?

```
public sealed class InputManager
{
  private System.Drawing.Point  mPos;

  public InputManager() 
  {
    mPos = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
  }
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  public void Update()
  {
    mPos = myForm.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of garbage are you talking about?

Comment: Heap allocation, which would need to be garbage collected eventually.

Comment: And this is a problem, because... ?

Comment: Since Point is a value type there is no obvious heap-allocation happening in the posted code.

Comment: I know! I am using the same variable to store the location, not recreating it, but the Performance Wizard VS2010 says it allocates memory. Running GC.GetTotalMemory(false) also shows that.

Comment: Have you used a profiler to verify that this code is actually causing your glitches? I very much doubt it.

Comment: .Net memory allocation profiling, VS2010

Comment: Maybe you can try calling the PointToClient method less often?

Comment: It's part of an Update loop dude. I need to call it that often. It shouldn't be creating new instances on the Heap!

Comment: I think you're going to need to find a design where you only call `PointToClient` when you actually need to use the result.

Comment: @Jon Because getting two integers is SOOOO complicated a task, right? There is no way on earth to get two integers returned without creating heap allocations, right?

Comment: Post a better (larger) code fragment. Is there a lambda involved?

Comment: Done. There is no lambda involved.

Comment: If you simply store `Control.MousePosition`, does that have the same memory impact? If not, then clearly `PointToClient()` is the issue. If that's the case, then I would store `MousePosition` and call `PointToClient()` when consuming the value.

Comment: Yes, PointToClient() is the issue. I need the value calculated too often for the memory allocation to be acceptable. Why does .net allocate on the heap when the process is really just two integer subtractions (Screen coordinate - Client Top Left) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) for `PointToClient()`

```
public Point PointToClient(Point p) { 
    return PointToClientInternal(p);
} 

internal Point PointToClientInternal(Point p) { 
    NativeMethods.POINT point = new NativeMethods.POINT(p.X, p.Y); 
    UnsafeNativeMethods.MapWindowPoints(NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, new HandleRef(this, Handle), point, 1);
    return new Point(point.x, point.y); 
}
```

`PointToClient()` calls `PointToClientInternal()`, which creates a new instance of `NativeMethods.POINT`.

Here's `NativeMethods.POINT`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public class POINT {
    public int x; 
    public int y; 

    public POINT() { 
    }

    public POINT(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y;
    } 
}
```

So I think this is where your heap allocation is coming from. Calling `PointToClient()` causes a new `NativeMethods.POINT` object to be instantiated (note that this is a class, not a struct).

If this is a problem in your application, I suggest only calling `PointToClient()` when you actually need the value. You might also look at using [`MapWindowPoints()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly, but that may or may not be advisable.

Comment: Thank You! Why didn't the C# team keep a lazy static NativeMethods.POINT somewhere? I'll have to do that myself I guess. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It does not produce garbage, because you are using `struct` which is a value type. There is no collection pressure and even if it would is that an issue? Doesn't look like a bottleneck of the game.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but VS disagrees.


Functions Allocating Most Memory:

System.Windows.Forms.Control.PointToClient(valuetype System.Drawing.Point)


System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_MousePosition()

Comment: Paste the whole code. Do you have closed-over local variables or is there a iterator block?

Comment: there is nothing to paste. I have a member variable mpos, of type System.Drawing.Point and on Update() I change its value with 

mpos = myForm.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)